# Selenium with Apache Poi Save error messages in Excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

I have Excel file that I reading test parameters.
I'd like to save error messages that show up during test in the same Excel File. I created column in Excel named: "status".
Example of my code with an error message:

```
if((Konfiguration.get("some excel parametr").equalsIgnoreCase("metro"))) {
    throw new RuntimeException("My error messages"); 
}
```

How can i save this error messages in Excel file in column named "status"

Answer (score 0):

to write into specific columns in your excel file.

1. Get the column and row that you need to write
2. Write the data in the obtained column.

if your row value is 2 and column is 5, then open your excel using apache poi and traverse to your particular cell and write your message.

```
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(File_path));

        HSSFWorkbook yourworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

        HSSFSheet sheet1 = yourworkbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Row row = sheet1.getRow(2);
        Cell column = row.getCell(5);
        column.setCellValue(your_error_message);
```

You can also use a pointer to track which column you have written during the last write.